# How to 3D plot exp(x/y) using python?

Tags: python

I've been trying to do a 3D surface plot of exp(x/y) but I can't figure out how, this function has many singularities that I don't know how to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Really? I can think of one, namely when y is close to zero, which is a problem with division, not the exp function. Avoid the zero and you'll be fine. This works, for instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

lim = 11
x = np.arange(-lim, lim*1.0001, 2)
y = np.arange(-lim, lim*1.0001, 2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.exp(X/Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```